# How can I write my own page in moodle?

Tags: php

- I want to write my own page in moodle that call with a link on the
  blocks (left side of the page)

  when I click that link I want to load my page (php) in the region
  field without change the other parts of the page
- note that the link is added by mine

Answer (score 1):

If it must be a php page the easiest way to do this is to

1. copy the index.php page in the root directory
2. replace everything between print_container_start() (right after middle-column column is printed) and print_container_end() with your code
3. Optional - delete conditionals that checks moodle version numbers

omitting step three shouldn't do any harm it will just make some needless upgrade checks.

Comment: thanks but the index.php in the root directory doesn't have print_container_start() & print_container_end()